# the code still print 0 and it can't calculate the required task

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, G;
    float num[500], sum=0.0, average,Grades;

    cout << "Enter the numbers of data: ";
    cin >> n;

    while (n > 500 || n <=  0)
    {
        cout << "Error! number should in range of (1 to 500)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number again: ";
        cin >> n;
    }

    for(G = 0; G < n; ++G)
    {
        cout << G + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[G];
        sum += num[G];
    }


    average = sum / n;
    Grades = num[G] >= average;
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    cout << "Grades Average = " << average << endl;
    cout << "Grades above or equal the Average : " <<Grades<< endl;
    cout << "Number of grades above the Average = "<<(int) Grades;
    
    return 0;
}
```

i coded this code but the `Number of grades above the Average` and `Grades above or equal the Average` don't work it just print 0

i tried to print the Grades  >= the avg but it print 0

also num of Grades  also print 0

where is the error ?

Comment: `float >= float` can only produce `true` aka `1` or `false` aka `0`. It's just a comparison, it doesn't count anything.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help so do you mean i have to add while loop or if to print       Number of grades above the Average and Grades above or equal the Average

Comment: That's one way to calculate the average. Without changing the rest of the code, I would personally do `Grades = std::count_if(num, num+n, [&](float v){return v >= average;}); ` instead.

Comment: `Grades = num[G] >= average;` goes out of bounds of the user's input, since `G` equals `n` at that line (which will exceed the array if `n` is 500). It is also not the correct way to count the number of array elements that match the criteria. Use a loop instead to count the elements, like you did with the `sum`. Or, use the standard `std::count_if()` algorithm, like Frank showed (though, I would have the lambda capture `average` by value instead of by reference).

Answer (score 1):

I think you was trying to do something like this:

```
...
int grades_on_avg, upper_grades = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
    cin >> num[i];
    sum += num[i];
       
}
average = sum / n;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) // use separate for loop and redefined index
{
    if(num[i] == average) // compare to average
        grades_on_avg++;
    else if(num[i] > average) // if bigger than average
        upper_grades++;
}



cout<<endl;

cout << "Grades Average = " << average << endl;
cout << "Grades above or equal the Average =" << (grades_on_avg + upper_grades) << endl;
cout << "Number of grades above the Average = "<< upper_grades ;
```

Comment: Thanks now i can understand it you are the man ! But i want ask how to print entered number that >= avg ?

Comment: It don't print the grade number it self it just print num of grade above not the number of mark

Comment: It is not clear for me to distinguish what number is what but from the code, as I understand if you want to get the index of grades that are above or equal to the average grades, you should initiate an array with the value of `grades_on_avg + upper_grades` then, you can iterate over the array and get the index of them. If you don't want to iterate over again just make an array with the same size as the `num` array and assign those values in the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You assign boolean value to `Grades` variable. Also, you refer to element outside of the array: `G` variable is equal to `n` after exiting for-loop, but max index you can use is `n - 1` (basic programming rule). So, you should change your code into something like this:

```
...
int avgGrades{0};
int avgAboveGrades{0};

for(int i{0}; i < n; ++i)
{
    if(num [i] == average)
    {
        ++avgGrades;
    }
    else if(num [i] > average)
    {
        ++avgAboveGrades;
    }
}
```

If you prefer more elegant ways of doing so, you can use `std::count_if()` function but it's more tricky and requires knowledge about lambdas.